# Вывод данных из виджета Label по щелчку мыши

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, lambda

Изучаю Python и tkinter в частности

Прошу помощи в обработке события в окне tkinter.

Есть поле типа Label, которое заполняется циклом. Одна итерация - одна строка. Необходимо при щелчке мышкой по какой либо строке выдавать данные из этой строки. Сколько не пытался, происходит вывод последней строки.

Подскажите, как сделать вывод конкретной строки

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial


class MainInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("600x350")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.window['padx'] = 10
        self.window['pady'] = 10

        list = []

        def font_config(widget, fontslant, event):
            widget.configure(font=fontslant)

        def print_row(row):
            print(row)

        for i in range(5):
            list += ["Это сторока {} по счету".format(i)]

            label = ttk.Label(self.window, text=list[i])
            label.bind("<Enter>", partial(font_config, label, "Helvetica 9 bold"))
            label.bind("<Button-1> ", func=lambda event: print_row(list[i]))
            label.bind("<Leave>", partial(font_config, label, "Helvetica 9"))
            label.grid(row=i, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

program = MainInterface()
program.window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте:

```
label.bind("<Button-1> ", func=lambda event: print_row(list[i]))
```

на:

```
label.bind("<Button-1> ", func=lambda event, text=list[i]: print_row(text))
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно то, что было нужно!

Comment: @Luarvick, тогда [отметьте и примите ответ :)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)